determining if a function on a total order is increasing
Hello I was thinking about the following questions but didn't find anything online about.
Let $(X, <)$ be a total order, and let $f \colon X \xrightarrow{} X$ be a function such that $f(x) < f(y) \implies x < y \:$ for all $x, y \in X$. Is $f$ injective? Is $f$ strictly increasing?
Any help/ nudge in the right direction is appreciated :)

By the contrapositive, $x\geq y$ implies that $f(x) \geq f(y)$. Therefore $f$ is nondecreasing.

And every non-decreasing function satisfies the condition, too. So these are equivalent.
